# GroupBy and Sum Typescript restructure Rest API

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest

Need help!!!!  I am trying to restructure objects within an api endpoint.  So, what I did is I created a method that calls the service which looks like this:

```
getData() {
    this.branchService.getBranchPipeline()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.branches = res;

      let datas = this.branches;

      this.dataProduct = datas.reduce((unit: any, item: any) => {
  
        let unitItem = unit.find((u: any) => u.fields['Fields.CUST01FV'] === item.fields['Fields.CUST01FV']);
        
        if(unitItem){
          unitItem.fields['Fields.16'] += Number(item.fields['Fields.16']);
          unitItem.fields['Loan.LoanAmount'] += Number(item.fields['Loan.LoanAmount']);
        }else{
          unit.push(item)
        }
        return unit;
      },[])
      
      console.log(this.dataProduct)
    })
  }
```

What I am trying to do is groupby and sum so I can create a report within a table which looks like this:

[Image of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qosjk.png)

What's happening is it is concatenating instead of giving me the sum.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like the value of Loan.LoanAmount and/or Fields.16 is a string, and for the first item with a particular Fields.CUST01FV, you place the object directly in the array. Subsequent items with the same Fields.CUST01FV use += on the two (string) values, which concatenates. You should probably parse the fields with Number(...) or parseInt when first adding the item to the array, instead of adding it as-is.

Comment: @Mack That is exactly what is happening.  Do you think you can you give me an example?

Comment: Looks like the existing value might be a string. Try casting it as well.
`unitItem.fields['Fields.16'] = Number(unitItem.fields['Fields.16']) + Number(item.fields['Fields.16']);`

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Thanks Ben!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the data being passed to your code stores the fields as strings, so when you store the object as-is as the first item with a given ID, the value remains as a string and subsequent amounts are concatenated to that string (in Javascript, `string += number` will return a string.)

We can fix this by constructing a new object instead to store the relevant counters as numbers.

Rather than search through the array for an item with a matching "Fields.CUST01FV" each time, it's also much more efficient to use an object mapping this ID (as the key) to the sum object (as the value).

It might be a good idea to define a type for this "sum object" to enforce type safety.

```
getData() {
  this.branchService.getBranchPipeline().subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    this.branches = res;

    let datas = this.branches;

    this.dataProduct = datas.reduce((unit: any, item: any) => {
      // look up an existing sum item by it's CUST01FV 
      let unitItem = unit[item.fields["Fields.CUST01FV"]];
      
      // if we have an existing "sum" item, add to the totals
      if (unitItem) {
        unitItem.field16 += Number(item.fields["Fields.16"]);
        unitItem.loanAmount += Number(item.fields["Loan.LoanAmount"]);
      } else {
        // otherwise, store initial totals from this item
        unit[item.fields["Fields.CUST01FV"]] = {
          field16: Number(item.fields["Fields.16"]),
          loanAmount: Number(item.fields["Loan.LoanAmount"]),
        };
      }
      return unit;
    }, {});

    console.log(this.dataProduct);
  });
}
```